# How to copy files from Hard Drive on a system with the Blue Screen of Death (BSOD)

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, data-recovery

I have a friend who has a computer that will not boot. He says that When he tries to boot he gets a Blue Screen of Death (BSOD). Is it possible to copy the files from the HDD even if the OS will not load? I was thinking that if he used a Linux boot USB that it would be possible to copy the files over to a new hard drive, then use diskpart to clean and reformat the old drive.

Is it possible?

Comment: Your friend should not panic (yet), but instead capture info from the BSOD, and find the root cause.  For instance a bad driver can cause a BSOD; has he tried a "safe boot"?

Answer (score 4):

> I was thinking that if he used a Linux boot USB that it would be
>   possible to copy the files over to a new hard drive, then use diskpart
>   to clean and reformat the old drive.

Assuming the hard drive in the failing system is readable and can be mounted, that should be possible.

But the thing with failing systems is until you know the cause of the failure, perhaps the system itself is failing to the point it just won’t boot anything. Or maybe for all you know the hard drive itself could be screwed up. But trying to boot from a Linux boot USB or CD and then seeing if you can read the hard drive should be a good, safe first step.

If somehow that doesn’t work, the next step would be to physically pull the hard drive from the failing machine and placing it an external enclosure. Like a USB-to-SATA enclosure or maybe even a USB data cable that allows you to hook up PATA/IDE as well as SATA drives.

Then just mount the drive on a working system, copy the files and take it all from there.